# What is the best way to cache in memory and update with go-routine?

Tags: caching, go

**The Case:** Weather API - I will assume that the task is simple and I just want to make an API to return the weather based on another API

**The code**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type ResponseBody struct {
    CurrentObservation struct {
        Weather         string `json:"weather"`
        Temperature     string `json:"temperature_string"`
        DisplayLocation struct {
            City string `json:"city"`
        } `json:"display_location"`
    } `json:"current_observation"`
}

var weather ResponseBody

func main() {
    // start the api
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}

// handler
func HomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // load the weather first
    weather = getWeather()
    b, _ := json.Marshal(weather)
    w.Write(b)
}

// get wether from wunderground api
func getWeather() ResponseBody {
    url := "http://api.wunderground.com/api/MY_API_KEY/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    var rb ResponseBody
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &rb)
    return rb
}
```

Now every time someone hits the API it will send a request to the weather API, but this won't be efficient when I will have concurrent requests, so I will cache it in memory and will update the data in a go-routine every one second

First: I will move the getWeather call to the main function

```
func main() {
    // load the weather first
    weather = getWeather()
    // start the api
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}

// handler
func HomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    b, _ := json.Marshal(weather)
    w.Write(b)
}
```

and will start a go-routine in the main function too

```
func main() {
    // load the weather first
    weather = getWeather()
    // update data every 1 second
    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
            weather = getWeather()
        }
    }()
    // start the api
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
```

so now the application could handle concurrent requests up to minimum 250 concurrent after testing with siege tool

```
Transactions:                250 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:               0.47 secs
Data transferred:           0.03 MB
Response time:              0.00 secs
Transaction rate:         531.91 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.07 MB/sec
Concurrency:                2.15
Successful transactions:         250
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:            0.04
Shortest transaction:           0.00
```

So is it right to cache and update data in this way? Or there is something wrong and I should do it in a better way?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that approach. Whether it's the best approach for a specific situation depends on factors not discussed.

Answer (score 9):

The basic approach is OK, but there's a data race on `weather`.  Use a [mutex](https://godoc.org/sync#RWMutex) to protect the variable:

```
var mu sync.RWMutex
var weather ResponseBody

func main() {
    // load the weather first
    weather = getWeather()
    // update data every 1 second
    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
            mu.Lock()
            weather = getWeather()
            mu.Unlock()
        }
    }()
    // start the api
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}

func HomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    mu.RLock()
    b, _ := json.Marshal(weather)
    mu.RUnlock()
    w.Write(b)
}
```

It is not necessary to guard the first assignment to `weather` in `main` because the assignment is [guaranteed to happen before](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_5) the updating goroutine and the request handlers started by `ListenAndServer`.

An improvement is to cache the response body bytes:

```
var mu sync.RWMutex
var resp []byte

func main() {
    // load the weather first
    weather := getWeather()
    resp, _ = json.Marshal(weather)
    // update data every 1 second
    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
            mu.Lock()
            weather = getWeather()
            resp, _ = json.Marshal(weather)
            mu.Unlock()
        }
    }()
    // start the api
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}

func HomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    mu.RLock()
    b := resp
    mu.RUnlock()
    w.Write(b)
}
```

Comment: Minor point, but technically the initializations should be guarded by the mutex too.

Comment: @JeremyHuiskamp Because the [memory model](https://golang.org/ref/mem#)  guarantees that the initialization completes before the goroutines run, there's no need to guard the initializations.